# Paypal integration for iphone app with live appID

Tags: ios, paypal

i have integrated paypal in my app and it works fine in sandbox but now i want to make live run on live app id so what i need to do ?.i just want to know about the live app id for paypal.does paypal provides app id after the approval of ios app? and we need to use app id and username in our app right? in short i need to know the process of testin app on live paypal account before submitting for apple. this question may be duplicated but there is no clear understandabe answer in prior question so please help if you know.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to the www.x.com then follow the steps

1. login with your paypal id
2. go to my account
3. under my application section select new app
4. select new app
5. fill up the form with details.
6. click submit app and you will get the Live app id  for you app

thats it..!!

Comment: Hey there is a section 
"Additional Testing Files (Ad Hoc files required for mobile app submissions)". 
i dont know which file i can upload here .

Answer (score 2):

Your app should reviewed and assigned with LiveID from the paypal people.So do the steps mentioned by @Jayraj Gohil.

Sandbox is used only for testing your integration and checking.So get the live id befor ur appstore binary upload

Comment: You shud have paypal account for submission of ur app for review. As like sandbox id, you will get LiveId after your Paypal Review

Comment: Paypal approved my app and provide me a live app Id now what?